# Returning only id's of records that meet criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to return distinct ID's of records which meet following conditions :
must have records with field reason_of_creation = 1
and must NOT have records with field reason_of_creation = 0 or null
in the same time.
While i was able to do it, i keep wondering is there more elegant (even recommended) way of doing it.

Here is anonymized version of what i have :

```
select distinct st.some_id from (
        select st.some_id, wanted.wanted_count as wanted, unwanted.unwanted_count as unwanted
          from some_table st
          left join (
                select st.some_id, count(st.reason_of_creation) as wanted_count
                  from some_table st
                 where st.reason_of_creation=1
                 group by st.some_id
                 ) wanted on wanted.some_id = st.some_id
          left join (
                select st.some_id, count(st.reason_of_creation) as unwanted_count
                  from some_table st
                 where st.reason_of_creation=0
                 group by st.some_id
                 ) unwanted on unwanted.some_id = st.some_id
where wanted.wanted_count >0 and (unwanted.unwanted_count = 0 or unwanted.unwanted_count is null)
   ) st;
```

Sample data :

```
some_id    reason_of_creation
      1           1
      1           0
      2           1
      3           null
      4           0
      4           1
      5           1
```

desired result would be list of records with `some_id = 2, 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me your query is overkill,all you need is some post aggregation filtering

```
SELECT some_id FROM t
GROUP BY some_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN reason_of_creation = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0
AND SUM(CASE WHEN reason_of_creation = 0 OR reason_of_creation IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=0
```

Comment: thats exactly what i hoped to get here, more simple way of doing it, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

I think that more elegant query exists and it is based on assumption what reasoson_of_crdeation field is integer, so minimal possible it's value, which greater than 0 is 1

This is for possible negative values for reasoson_of_crdeation:

```
select someid from st
where reasoson_of_crdeation != -1
group by someid
having(min(nvl(abs(reasoson_of_crdeation), 0)) = 1)
```

or

```
select someid from st
group by someid
having(min(nvl(abs(case when reasoson_of_crdeation = -1 then -2 else reasoson_of_crdeation end), 0)) = 1)
```

And this one in a case if reasoson_of_crdeation is non-negative integer:

```
select someid from st
group by someid
having(min(nvl(reasoson_of_crdeation, 0)) = 1)
```